# how to add filter on output of sql query to get answer as boolean?

Tags: sql, node.js, oracle

I have one table in which ids are mentioned and values for that id.

```
id  | value
101 | admin
102 | user
103 | test
104 | admin
105 | basic
```

I get input as 2 ids. now, I have to check whether these two ids have equal value or not? This id field is foreign key in some other table.

so far I tried this:
select id, value from roles where id in('101', '104')

but I want output to be as - not equal or equal or return some value only if equal, empty output if not equal.

Note: values will be never be null

I am using oracle 12 and node.js.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can the "value" be `null`? If it can, how should that be handled? One possibility: consider the "values" as equal if they are both non-`null` or equal, or if both are `null`. There are other possible choices: for example, `null` is not equal to anything, not even another `null`. So, to make your problem description complete, you must either say "the column is `not null`" or else you must tell us exactly how `null` values should be handled for determining if two values are "equal".

Comment: @mathguy values will never be null

Comment: Couple of notes: (1) Boolean data type is not supported in Oracle SQL (even though the SQL Standard requires Boolean to be supported...); PL/SQL does support Boolean, but that does not extend to plain SQL. (2) Why are you comparing `id` to strings like '101' and '104'? Is the `id` data type `varchar2` - and if it is, why? It seems the data type should be `number`, and the `in` list should be numbers, not strings.

Comment: This is just example. actual id field is alphaNumeric with dataType as varchar only.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way.

```
select case when min(value) = max(value) then 'equal' else 'not equal' end
       as compare_values
from   roles
where  id in ('101', '104')
;
```

This works even if you pass three or more id's - it just tells you if ALL the values (for ALL the id's) are equal.

Note that if `value` can be `null` (you said that's not the case in **your** real-life data), the `null` values will be ignored; the query will return `'equal'` if all non-`null` values are equal.

Comment: n what happens if value is numeric and I want to return higher value among 2?

Comment: @pride - then you could do something like this: `select case when min(value) != max(value) then max(value) end as max_value from .....` (the rest is the same). This will return the max value when the values are **not** equal, and `null` otherwise. Use the `then` (and, if needed, `else`) clause(s) of the `case` expression to return whatever you need in each case. The only constraint is that the same data type should be returned from both branches - you can't return number in one case but string in the other.